# ItemsControl within ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol

(*After pulling hair for 8 consecutive hours, I've given up. Will be very thankful if someone could come to rescue*):

Here's what I have:

**AlbumItem**: This is an `ItemsControl` that uses a `Canvas` as its `ItemsPanel` and binds to a colletion property of the underlying VM. A handful of `DataTemplate`s  defined in `Resources` section of this control perform conversion of ViewModel objects into UI objects. This control works really nicely and as expected.

**Album**: This again is an `ItemsControl` that uses a `UniformGrid` as its `ItemsPanel` and binds to a colletion property of the underlying VM. This control shows a grid of `AlbumItem`s. I have set the `ItemTemplate` of this control to `AlbumItem`.

No matter what I do, this second control doesn't use its `ItemTemplate` to display its items. `UniformGrid` works nicely and I get a 3 x 3 grid of items, but each of those items is a simple `TextBlock` showing the class name of the underlying VM object.

I have tried to use a `DataTemplate` too, instead of using `ItemTemplate`, to no avail.

Can anyone see where is it going wrong?

## Edit

Posting a working sample would be a huge undertaking (this is a complex project), but I can post relevant XAML here:

**AlbumItem**

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="AlbumItem" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:bd="clr-namespace:ViewProject" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModelProject" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"
         ClipToBounds="True" Background="LightYellow">
<ItemsControl.Resources>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2VConverter" />
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Ellipse}">
    <Ellipse IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="{Binding BorderThickness}" Fill="{Binding Fill, Mode=OneWay}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke, Mode=OneWay}" />
  </DataTemplate>  
</ItemsControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Focusable="true" Width="{Binding Size.Width}" Height="{Binding Size.Height}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
     </Canvas>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Location.X}" />
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Location.Y}" />
      <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Path=GlobalZOrder}" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Album**

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="Album"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:bd="clr-namespace:ViewProject" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModelProject" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="800"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Drawing.Baked}" 
         ClipToBounds="True">

  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="vm:ReadonlyDrawingVM">
      <bd:AlbumItem />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have used Snoop to confirm the following:

- Album's `DataContext` is correct. So is its `ItemsSource`. I can actually see all the VM objects in Snoop when I delve `ItemsSource`.
- By default Album doesn't show anything at all. If I use Snoop to reset `ItemTemplate` and/or `ItemsPanel` properties of Album, I see all the items (i.e. a TextBlock with their class name) in the form of a grid or list depending upon the property that I reset.
- AlbumItem works fine with design-time XML data. Album doesn't.

Comment: Post the XAML code and the code that you used to bind to the data. Any number of things could be wrong, eg incorrect XAML, incorrect bindings, *not* providing any AlbumItems to bind, using the wrong binding syntax to bind to AlbumItems

Comment: Yea, we'll need to see under the hood dude.

Comment: I would recommend you create a similar test project which mimics the problem and post that...by providing data/xaml that will increase the chances of someone providing an answer or the exercise will reveal the problem due to the architect it from scratch.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Sorry I had to leave my desk. Plz check my edit. I have added a bunch of relevant XAML code.

Comment: Assuming Album is setting your DataContext, and you have AlbumItem sitting in a DataTemplate, can you do something like `{Binding Path=Children.DataContext, ElementName=Album}` to reach out to it?

Comment: @ChrisW.: `Children.DataContext`? Or you mean `DataContext.Children`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be due to the underlying data source. I was binding Album with a `List<T>`, which didn't update the UI with the changes in its items due to the following line of the underlying property `Baked`:

```
If _Baked Is value Then Return
```

This is the first line in `Baked` property setter (I'm using the default property template provided by MVVM Light). Since I never assigned a new `List<T>` to `_Baked`; only changed items within it, the above line would stop property change notification from being raised. Once I fixed this, my Album started getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to write smallest possible project that mimicks your code - I guess that I got the same problem as you and I got TextBlocks for my AlbumItem VMs.

For me was working to use `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` in `AlbumItem`, but directly - not via `ItemsControl.Resources`. After some experiments, it look like ContentPresenter used for AlbumItems can't find the default DataTemplate for the VM.

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="so_wpf_32587588.AlbumItemView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:soWpf32587588="clr-namespace:so_wpf_32587588">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}"/>
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZOrder}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="soWpf32587588:AlbumItemView">
            <Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" Fill="{Binding ItemBrush}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I had similar problem when I was writing kind of custom ResourceDictionary - I experienced that dictionary was already parsed, but not available in hash used by ResourceDictionary, so any controls which needed the resource got only default instead of defined resource.

You can try to put your DataTemplate in higher places of visual (resource) tree and see what happens.